# How to segment a binary image with a strokes?

Tags: c++

There is a problem in SPOJ [Hard Image Recognition](http://SPOJ.com/problems/HIR). I trained an ANN using python then I got the model. I'm going to apply the model to the SPOJ data testing. Before that, I need to clean up the noises. One of the [image: example] has a stroke. I need to denoise it first before the segmentation process. Anyone has an idea to segment an image that robust to noises using cpp?

Comment: Do you mean the one that is crossed out (i.e. 189765)? You could carefully erode the image and then dilate it again, this is called [image opening](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/open.htm).

Comment: Yes. But i need to do it in cpp. Is it possible?